# Angular injector error with self invocation function syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a basic angular app, with self invoking function

```
(function(){})
```

When ever I am running the application it is throwing injector error, if I remove the above code, it is working fine, I have gone through many sites but unable to fix this, and why it is happening I am unable to understand.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
(function(){
  angular.module("myApp", [])  
});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/eRo1CNRz6sIAIVLZTDWH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have like this,

```
(function(){
  angular.module("myApp", [])  
})();
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eRo1CNRz6sIAIVLZTDWH?p=preview)

Comment: thank u very much... will accept the ans in anthr 10mns